# How to Prevent Opacity for Sub Div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added the opacity for the main div as `opacity:0.5` I also have the sub div contain message. 
HTML:

```
<div id="word_wrap">
    <div id="top_div">
        Hi Folks Nice to Meet you
            </div>
</div>
<input id="floating_button" type="button" value="Click Me"/>
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVQTh/
Now it opacity appear fully on the div include sub div. but i want to show the sub div without opacity , with background opacity. Is it possible to do that in jquery or css.

In the above fiddle i make the sub div background as red. I want to show the sub div without opacity. How to exclude the opacity for the sub div itself or corresponding div itself.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really simple, you can't do that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the opacity on an element, all children of that element has an opacity of 1, but as they are inside the parent element, the opacity set on the parent element will also affect the children elements as well, so you can not set the opacity of a child to be "more visible" than the parent, as the childs opacity is already 1.

The closest you'll get is rgba colors, which are not supported in all browsers :

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JVQTh/2/)

This sets the background color to red with an alpha (opacity) of 0.5 without setting the opacity on the entire element, or it's children.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome response. Thank you so much